# Received webhook notification but with empty data in servicem8

Tags: post, webhooks

I can successfully register the webhook in serviceM8. By list the webhook subscriptions i got the result like this
[{"object":"job","callback_url":"http://ABC.XYZ/oauth/webhook/m8","fields":["active","payment_processed","uuid","company_uuid"],"active":true}]

But when i try to create new job & approve the job in servicem8, i received the notification from serviceM8 but the data in body is all empty like :

body: { '{"object":"JOB","entry":': { '"payment_processed"': '' } }

Am i missing something in webhook setup ???

Answer (score 0):

Webhook notifications will not include the data record itself, only a reference to the record that has been changed/updated.

Your callback url should be receiving a JSON body similar to the example here (under Handling Webhooks):
http://developer.servicem8.com/docs/platform-services/webhooks/

Once you receive the notification, you will need to request the updated record using the supplied resource_url.

Comment: I am expecting the uuid of updated job and also resource_url as the document . But here are example that i received :
{"object":"JOB","entry":":{"active","uuid","company_uuid":"}